# Chinese developer notice: run tomcat 7.0 using eclipse juno throw exception

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

When I try to run the tomcat 7.0 using the eclipse juno I encountered a problem. The console throw exception saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a really stupid mistake, I put the tomcat into a path with **Chinese character** in it like /Users/thomas/Desktop/源码包/tomcat, and as soon as I put the folder into a path without any Chinese character, problem solved!

Comment: Sounds like a flaw in Tomcat to me.